# pre_get_posts : 'post__not_in' doesn't work with global variable

Tags: query, exclude, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to set a `post__not_in` which use a global `$popular` variable, defined in the `index.php`.

-index.php-

```
$popular[] = 1 //post id=1
$popular[] = 2 //post id=2
$popular[] = 3 //post id=3
```

-functions.php-

```
function modify_query_exclude_popular($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()){
        global $popular;
        $query->set('post__not_in', $popular);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'modify_query_exclude_popular' );
```

I just can't make it work, the loop is working, but popular post_ids aren't exluded. I tried everything: define a constant, using "create_function" etc...

PS: If I set `$popular` array inside the function `modify_query_exclude_popular()` it does work, but I absolutely need to set the array in `index.php` (the `$popular` use post_id of another loop).

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `$popular` to be global before you use it. Based on the code you've posted you haven't done that.

```
global $popular;
$popular[] = 1 //post id=1
$popular[] = 2 //post id=2
$popular[] = 3 //post id=3
```

However, if you mean the `index.php` in the theme, that file is not always used. You may be defining the variable in a file that does not load when you need it to. It is hard to tell whether this is the case due to the limited code you posted.

`pre_get_posts` is going to run before any of the theme files anyway, except, if `functions.php` (or any files included from there). You can echo values out from that filter and from `header.php` to prove that to yourself.

Also, there may be a better way to do this than to declare a global variable. Again, due to the limited code it is hard to say.

Overall, it sounds like you need to rethink how you are going to accomplish this. A much better description of what you are trying to accomplish would help.

## Reference

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

INDEX.php file is refined far after the `pre_get_posts` hook... so, you should define the `$popular` variable before that hook.